# move back to the previous screen after saving and updating new entry with getx flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, odoo, flutter-getx

Devs I'm trying to get back to the previous page after creating and updating an entry but once I submit the data it takes me to another screen. once I click the back button the form again opens and then I again have to press back to go back to the previous page in a flutter.

```
// ignore_for_file: deprecated_member_use, prefer_interpolation_to_compose_strings, use_build_context_synchronously, unused_element, unused_import, prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables, unrelated_type_equality_checks
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:asanhisab/utils/helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';

import '../services/remoteservices.dart';
import 'ledger.dart';

// void main() => runApp(EditLedger());

class EditLedger extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditLedger({
    Key? key,
    required this.id,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String id;

  @override
  State<EditLedger> createState() => _EditLedgerState();
}

class _EditLedgerState extends State<EditLedger> {
  var ledger = [];
  bool isloaded = false;
  bool isChecked = true;
  var headtypeValue = '';
  bool selHeadType = false;
  var headName = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var openingBalance = TextEditingController();
  static const List<String> headTypeList = <String>[
    "Select",
    "income",
    "expense",
    "asset",
    "liability",
    "cash",
    "bank"
  ];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLedgerDatabyid(int.parse(widget.id));
  }

  getLedgerDatabyid(id) async {
    ledger = await RemoteServices()
        .getRecordById('ah_general_ledger.ah_account_head', id);
    logger.d(ledger);
    headName.text = ledger[0]['name'];
    headtypeValue = ledger[0]['head_type'];
    openingBalance.text = ledger[0]['opening_balance'].toString();
    setState(() {
      isloaded = true;
      if (headtypeValue == 'cash' || headtypeValue == 'bank') {
        selHeadType = true;
      } else {
        selHeadType = false;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('${ledger[0]['name']}'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Visibility(
            visible: isloaded,
            replacement: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 30, bottom: 7),
                      child: Text(
                        'Enter Name',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: headName,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: 'Enter Name',
                      ),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == '' || value == null) {
                          return "* This Field is required";
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),

                  const Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 12, bottom: 5),
                      child: Text(
                        'Head Type',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 0, bottom: 0),
                    //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 55.0,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      ),
                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            isCollapsed: true,
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                          value: headtypeValue,
                          items: headTypeList
                              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (String? value) {
                            openingBalance.text = '0.00';
                            // This is called when the user selects an item.
                            setState(() {
                              headtypeValue = value!;
                              if (value == 'cash' || value == 'bank') {
                                selHeadType = true;
                              } else {
                                selHeadType = false;
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          isExpanded: true,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == 'Select') {
                              return "*Please select Head Type";
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 8),
                    child: Row(
                      // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const Text(
                          'Is Active',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blueGrey,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Checkbox(
                          checkColor: Colors.white,
                          fillColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
                          value: ledger[0]['is_active'],
                          onChanged: (bool? value) {
                            setState(() {
                              isChecked = value!;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Opening Account
                  Visibility(
                    visible: selHeadType,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        const Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 0, bottom: 7),
                            child: Text(
                              'Opening Balance',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        // Opening Balance
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: openingBalance,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              hintText: 'Opening Balance',
                            ),
                            // onTap: _selDatePicker,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Margin Top
                  const SizedBox(height: 50),
                  // Payment Create Button
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 0, bottom: 25),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 250,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      child: FlatButton(
                        // onPressed: validate,
                        onPressed: () => {
                          updateAccountHead(
                              int.parse(widget.id),
                              headName.text.toString().trim(),
                              headtypeValue,
                              isChecked,
                              openingBalance.text)
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Update',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  updateAccountHead(id, name, type, isChecked, balance) async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      Map values = {
        "name": name,
        "head_type": type,
        "is_active": isChecked,
        "opening_balance": balance
      };
      logger.d(values);
      var update = await RemoteServices()
          .updateRecord('ah_general_ledger.ah_account_head', id, values);
      logger.d(update.toString());
      if (update == true) {
        return showDialog<void>(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Row(
                children: const [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.check_circle_outline,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Text('Success'),
                ],
              ),
              content: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ListBody(
                  children: const <Widget>[
                    Text('Created Successfully'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  child: const Text('ok'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Get.off(() => const GeneralLedgerScreen());
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        errorAlert(context, update);
      }
    } else {
      // logger.e('All Fields Required');
      errorScafold(context, '* Please Fill All the Required Fields!');
    }
  }
}

Color getColor(Set<MaterialState> states) {
  return Colors.blue;
}
```

```
  updateRecord(model, ids, values) async {
    var client = OdooClient(storage.read('link'));
    var authres = await client.authenticate(storage.read('email'),
        storage.read('password'), storage.read('dbname'));
    if (authres.isSuccess) {
      var recid = await client.write(model, [ids], values);
      if (recid.hasError()) {
        return recid.getError();
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      logger.e('Auth Error Occur');
    }
  }
```

hello, Devs I'm trying to get back to the previous page after creating and updating an entry but once I submit the data it takes me to another screen. once I click the back button the form again opens and I again have to press back to go back to the previous page in a flutter.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to go back the screen.
use

```
Get.back();
```

Sometimes in above case, only alert pop will close. if so use

```
Get.close(2);
```

instead of

```
Get.off(() => const GeneralLedgerScreen());
```